# Android hide NavigationView header

Tags: android, material-design

I am working on an android app and it requires **DrawerLayout** below the **ToolBar**. I've achieved that but NavigationView's header i.e `Status Bar 24dp` is visible even after removing the header. 
Is there a way to remove that?

[image: Problem]

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@null"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `app:headerLayout="@null"` from your navigationview.

inflate your headerlayout from onCreate() like this, and then set the visiblity gone.

```
 View headerView= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);
 navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);
 navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Already tried, no luck. By the way you see the top gray bar in the drawer. That is the problem. How can I make it translucent?

Comment: had you change background color of header layout to transparent ?

Comment: Is it gonna make a different? Even we are setting visibility to Gone?

Comment: Ok Show me the java code, where you are playing with headerview

Comment: `NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: dude, I checked my code in my navigation drawer.. and worked perfect

Comment: do it exactly i write in my answer. Remove   app:headerLayout="@null" from layout

Comment: and then inflate header layout and then make it visiblity gone

Comment: View headerView= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);
            navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView);
    navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_home);

headerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and remove the line app:headerLayout="@null" from your xml.

Answer (score 1):

Also try like this,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the height is not enough. Why don't you use `wrap_content` with `layout="@layout/app_bar_home"` and add `android:layout_below` to your `DrawerLayout`?

Or to keep it simple, you can also use `LinearLayout` in this case. It would be easier:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@null"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define groups in menu and then hide group using:

```
navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(groupPosition, false);
```

Also, remove **headerLayout** attribue.